# Splitting of String on encountering '-' between characters but not on numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to split the below String on '-' but the problem is that the split should only happen '-' when it has characters on both the sides.

```
String s = "1 - 2 Foo - Bar 3 - 4 Wrong - Right"
```

Ouptut

```
String[0] = 1 - 2 Foo
String[1] = Bar 3 - 4 Wrong
String[2] = Right
```

Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: `when it has String on both the sides`: do you mean "letters" on both sides?

Comment: try using a regex with lookahead and lookbehind

Comment: @raj I have tried this s.split("\\D\\s-") -it works but fails when this input is provided "1 - 2 a - b"

Comment: @ernest_k yes when letters on both the side

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z]) - (?=[a-zA-Z])
```

like this:

```
s.split("(?<=[a-zA-Z]) - (?=[a-zA-Z])")
```

Explanation:

`(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind, it checks to see if the stuff before the hyphen matches `[a-zA-Z]`, but doesn't actually matches them. The `(?=...)` is similar, but it looks *ahead* to see if the stuff on the right of the hyphen matches `[a-zA-Z]`.